# Ember.js filter content and use button action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I ran into the following problem: I've a controller and I want to filter the models, something like:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'product',

  filteredContent: function(query) {
    var query = this.get('query')

    var products = this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
      return true // Condition goes here
    })

    return products
  }.property('query')
})
```

Which is working fine in my view:

```
{{#each product in filteredContent}}
  ...
  <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
  ...
  <button {{action addToCart}}>Add to cart</button>
{{/each}}
```

At least as far as looping. The action `addToCart` doesn't work and leads to the error `Nothing handled the event 'addToCart'` when hitting the button. Even though it's defined in the `ProductController`.

Now here is the interesting part: if I don't use the filtered results, but just `each product in controller` in my view, the `addToCart` click is working. I guess there's something about the relation between views and controllers I don't understand, so I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `{{#each item in items}}` syntax [does not change the binding scope](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/).  Hence you have bind to `product.name`.  If the addToCart is in the ProductController and not the ProductsController, you will need to write your action binding as `action addToCart target="product"`.

Comment: Well `{{action product.addToCart}}` leads to `Nothing handled the event 'product.addToCart'`, since it's asking for that function on the model, not the `ProductController`, I assume.

Comment: I did move the logic into the model, but I had to call it like this:

`action addToCart target="product"`

That worked for me.

Comment: Shoot, that's right.  I'll update my answer so it doesn't confuse others :-)